# How and where call function in component conditionally based on redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

i have a component and in my component i have some child component.

in my parent component i have some function and i want to trigged it from child component. So i make it with redux.

It's my parent component:

```
   import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
    import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
    import { splashStop } from "store/actions/Home/splashStop";

import { connect } from "react-redux";

class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    };
    this.goPage = this.goPage.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

  goPage = () => {
     this.props.history.push("/agencies");
  };

  render() {
    if (this.props.homeSplash.splashStart == true) {
      myTime.play();
    }
    return (
      <div>
         <ChildComponent />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  homeSplash: state.homeSplash
});

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return {
    splashStop: bindActionCreators(splashStop, dispatch)
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(withRouter(Home));
```

it's my child component:

here is in my child component at onClick function i dispatch redux action:

```
  triggerSplash = () => {
    this.props.splashStart();
  };
```

my action:

export const START_SPLASH =
  "START_SPLASH";

```
export const splashStart = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({
            type: START_SPLASH,
            payload: true
          });
    };
  };
```

and my reducer:

```
import { START_SPLASH } from "store/actions/Home/splashStart";

let initialState = {
  splashStart: false
};

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case START_SPLASH:
      return { ...state, splashStart: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

my reducer, action is working correctly.

here is i wonder why `myTime.play();` working always when component mount it's just don't care this control:

```
if (this.props.homeSplash.splashStart == true) {
          myTime.play();
        }
```

i place it to wrong place or what ?

Comment: can you show how you have attached triggerSplash event .

Answer (score 0):

In your redux structure, it seems everything OK. But you should provide your childComponent also to make it more clear.
If you have connected redux action correctly in your child component then try this:

```html
<button ... onClick={() => this.triggerSplash()}>Click</button>
```

Put arrow function inside `onClick`. Because, in the component initialization, all component functions are called automatically in the render time.